# How to cat multi-line bash variables?

Tags: bash, variables, unix, cat

When I try to save columns of bash variables and then try to cat them together, I get an error.

These are the variables:

```
$ a_var=$(grep -i "word" {input} | awk '{print $3}')

$ echo $a_var
hello1
hello2
hello3

$ b_var=$(grep -i "otherword" {input} | awk '{print $3}')

$ echo $b_var
hello10
hello11
hello12
```

But then when I try:

```
$ new_var=$(cat $a $b)
```

I get some weird output that can't save to a file or a new variable.

```
cat: hello1: No such file or directory
cat: hello2: No such file or directory
cat: hello3: No such file or directory
cat: hello10: No such file or directory
cat: hello11: No such file or directory
cat: hello12: No such file or directory

$ echo $new_var

$
```

(When I "echo" there is a blank return.)

What is going on? How can I concatenate my bash variables together?

Edit: I want the output to look like this (I want to save this column of values to a file):

```
hello1
hello2
hello3
hello10
hello11
hello12
```

Comment: Use `printf '%s\n' "$a" "$b"`

Comment: maybe: ```new_var="$(cat $a $b)"```

Comment: @anita : Why do you mention arrays? There is no array in your example.

Comment: Which output do you want?

Comment: @anubhava's answer did it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Although `cat` in Linux stands for concatenate, it not going to act on variables. Actually, it is used to connect files and print to the standard output device. For your case, use `c_var="${a_var}${b_var}"`

Comment: Thanks for this helpful explanation. I changed my question to show that I'm looking to keep newline characters after each entry to maintain the columnar format. When I echo "${a_var}${b_var}" there is no newline between the first and second variable

Answer (score 2):

This is how you concatenate these string variables in shell:

c_var="$a_var$b_var" ; echo $c_var

Or generally: c="$a$b" ; echo $c